# Is there any way to check amount of components in angular app?

Tags: angular

As in title. Counting them by myself is the last thing I wanna do. Is there any 3rd part software that could do this calculation?

Comment: What's your OS and IDE?

Comment: Im working on MacOS/Ubuntu, and mostly VSCode. But if there is a difference i could switch to anything.

Comment: ```grep  -r '@Component' ./src | grep -c '@Component'```

Answer (score 3):

As long as you're happy to return *all* components within the file structure of your app, you could just perform a search in VS Code.

One way would be to set up the following search:

search

`export class`

files to include

`src/app/**/*.component.ts`

The number of files are returned in the search results.

[image: search criteria for finding number of components in VS Code]

This is a very simple method, and will return all components currently loaded in VS Code that match, regardless of whether or not they are in use in your project.

Answer (score 0):

You can install Augury Chrome extension tool. That will give the list of components as and when you navigate the pages. Please refer to the image below.

[Augury Extension](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X0HF6.png)