# How can i see/find the number of angular components in my app, with IntelliJ IDE?

Tags: angular, intellij-idea, find, components

I would like to **count the number of angular components** with **IntelliJ** IDE. I used 'find in files' search tool with terms "export class" but it includes more than components files.
Thanks =)
Etienne.

Comment: Pretty much the same as [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60376842/is-there-any-way-to-check-amount-of-components-in-angular-app), except for the IntelliJ part. In the end, it still boils down to the same search though...

Comment: Thanks Robby. Unfortunately, I did not find an answer in the link you sent me -> i saw it before asking my question. MoreOver, my english is terrible and i'm a novice with stackOverFlow too. So i post my first question...

Answer (score 0):

I'm using intellijIDE to count the number of component , just search using find in file after that put component.html and as you can see you have the list of components in your project :
[image]

I hope that can hepl you to resolve your issue .

Comment: Oh tkanks Rassakra, i didn't thought about it. I think it works : i have 34 results, so 34 components. I thank you =)